# mysql - update row with the current date

Tags: php, mysql

I have mySql query that keep in table "user_last_view" the last reservations user watched.

If user watch some reservation that already in the last 10 than nothing happened.

I would like to make a little change - if user watch reservation that is already in the table i would like to update the field "createDate" (timestamp type. if necessary i can change it to 'datetime') to the current time and date, even if it's not in the user last 10 watch reservations.

What should i change in my query?

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO user_last_view
            (userID,
             page,
             refid,
             mode) 
           SELECT ".$_SESSION['userDetails']['userID'].",
                  '".$page."',
                  ".$refID.", 
                  '".$mode."'
                  FROM dual
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                           FROM (SELECT ulv.userID,
                                                        ulv.page,
                                                        ulv.refid
                                                        FROM user_last_view ulv
                                                        ORDER BY ulv.createdate
                                                        DESC LIMIT 10) x
                                           WHERE x.userID = ".$_SESSION['userDetails']['userID']."
                                                 AND x.page = '".$page."'
                                                 AND x.refid = ".$refID.");
";

$conn->query($query);
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation (or interpolation) to get values into queries. That's error prone and makes you application vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (when use input can influence the values). Use parameterized queries instead.